# Simple inequality in C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Sorry the title is a bit vague.  Let A be a C*-algebra, and let x and y be positive elements in A.  Is it true that $$ \|x-y\|^2 \leq \|x^2-y^2\|? $$
Well, yes.  But the proof I have is a bit of a hack, so I wonder if anyone has a "nice" proof, or a reference?

Aside: if $A=C_0(X)$ then this reduces to the inequality $(a-b)^2 \leq |a^2-b^2|$ for non-negative real numbers a and b.

**Update:** Jonas points me to http://www.springerlink.com/content/j4756m418220644r/ where Kittaneh has a proof pretty similar to what I had in mind (unpack the proof of Theorem 1).  I guess I was interested in whether this sort of thing was standard (if I looked in the right textbook) or if it was a bit of a curiosity.  I think the latter seems more likely...

Comment: I don't know how "nice" it is compared to your hack, but Corollary 3 of http://www.springerlink.com/content/v74h482277288723/ implies this as a special case.

Comment: Or Corollary 2 of http://www.springerlink.com/content/j4756m418220644r/ with $p=\infty$. This is an earlier reference, cited by the other I gave.  (The case you're interested in actually follows from Theorem 1, so the more general Theorem 2 isn't needed.)

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, Kittaneh's proof is pretty similar to the proof I had in mind...

Comment: You're welcome.  That's why I only commented--I didn't know if this would be an appropriate "answer".

Comment: It just occurred to me that this gives another way to see that the distance between 2 projections is at most 1. I find that amusing, even though there are much simpler proofs. More generally, it is straightforward to show that $\|x-y\|\leq\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$ if $x$  and $y$   are positive. 

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` (and another in the comments) is broken.

Comment: It's broken for me to.  I am afraid that 12 years later, I have no recollection of what paper I meant to link to (lesson from the past: give author, title, and a doi or similar "permanent" link...!)

Comment: Ah, quite understandable... Thanks for taking a look, all the same!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theorem 1.5 of [this 1987 paper](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca:8443/dspace/handle/1828/1506) by J. Phillips says that if $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is a continuous operator monotone function and $a$ and $b$ are positive operators on a Hilbert space, then $\|f(a)-f(b)\|\leq f(\|a-b\|)-f(0)$.  I think that the proof is nice.  Corollary 1.6 says that $\|a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\|\leq\|a-b\|^{1/n}$, $n\geq1.$  Of course your inequality follows from taking $a=x^2$, $b=y^2$, and $n=2$.

Apparently Kittaneh and Kosaki have a similar approach in "Inequalities for the Schatten p-norm. V." Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci. 23 (1987), no. 2, 433--443 ([MR link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=890926)).  I haven't read any of this article.

Perhaps I should add the following for a more general audience. A continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is operator monotone if whenever $x$ and $y$ are positive operators such that $y-x$ is positive, it follows that $f(y)-f(x)$ is positive.  The functions $t\mapsto t^\alpha$ are operator monotone for $0<\alpha\leq1$ (but not for $\alpha>1$).

Comment: Ah, I like this!  (So accepted).  This operator monotone stuff is nice: I used to know about it some years ago, but forgot.  I guess, with hindsight, it's a good place to look.

Comment: By the way, that's some excellent detective work Jonas, as MathSciNet doesn't record this ever being published...?

Comment: I found it with Google's help, and what changed from the last time I searched was that I thought of searching for "generalized Powers Stormer inequality" and the like.  Yeah, I don't know how that worked in terms of publication: I guess it appeared in a U of Victoria "technical report", but I don't know if such things are refereed.  It's not like the author had a shortage of other publications, and I was speculating that the independent overlapping results of Kittaneh and Kosaki may have been a factor in the decision.  

Comment: The link to the 1987 paper by J. Phillips at `dspace.library.uvic.ca` seems to broken…

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so actually, decoding Phillip's work gives what I think is a very nice proof.

Let x and y be positive.  Let $\epsilon=\|x-y\|$ so as $x-y$ is self-adjoint, it follows that
$x \leq y+\epsilon 1$.  What seems to be a very standard inequality is that then $x^{1/2} \leq (y+\epsilon 1)^{1/2}$.  We then claim that $(y+\epsilon 1)^{1/2} \leq y^{1/2} + \epsilon^{1/2} 1$.  This follows by working in the commutative C*-algebra generated by y and 1, and using that $(s+t)^{1/2} \leq s^{1/2} + t^{1/2}$ for positive real numbers s and t.  So $$x^{1/2} - y^{1/2} \leq \epsilon^{1/2} 1$$and by symmetry, also $y^{1/2}-x^{1/2}\leq\epsilon^{1/2}1$.  Thus $\|x^{1/2}-y^{1/2}\|\leq\epsilon^{1/2}=\|x-y\|^{1/2}$ as required.

Comment: I agree that operator monotonicity of the square root is standard.  A good reference is Proposition 4.2.8 on page 250 of Kadison-Ringrose volume 1: http://books.google.com/books?id=JbxgKOwu2McC&lpg=PP1&dq=kadison%20ringrose&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q&f=false